# Posso invocar a function numa Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, funções, trigger

Minha *function* feita no Sql-Server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  dbo.getQuantidade(@idProd char)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @QTD float
      SET @QTD = (SELECT (prod.Quantidade)
      FROM Produto prod 
      where @id_prod = IdProduto)

return @QTD
END
```

Minha *Trigger* feito ORACLE:

```
create or replace trigger seq_PedidoItem
Before insert on PedidoItem
for each row
begin

    if(:new.Quantidade > getQuantidade(:new.IdProduto)) then

    raise_application_error(-20101, 'Quantidade Pedida abaixo da quantidade do Stock');

    end if;

    :new.ValorTotal:= :new.Quantidade * getValor(:new.IdProduto);

end;
/
```

Eu queria adaptar  o trigger para SQL Server. Alguém me pode dar uma ajuda na syntax ?

*Obs:* Eu estou com dúvida de como faço a `if` e como invoco a função na `trigger`.

Comment: Você quer chamar uma função feita no Sql-Server em uma trigger feita no Oracle?

Comment: Não não, Eu fiz a função em SQL Server, e também tenho essa função em Oracle, agora queria adoptar/transformar de forma a poder utilizar em SQL Server, tenho algumas dificuldades com a syntaxe em SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Posso invocar a function numa Trigger?

Sim você pode chamar uma function sem problema.

No seu caso para usar o seu `if` você pode reculpera os valores do `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` da `TRIGGER` com o `(SELECT IdProduto FROM INSERTED)`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION  dbo.getQuantidade(@idProd char)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @QTD float
      SET @QTD = (SELECT (prod.Quantidade)
      FROM Produto prod 
      where IdProduto = @idProd )

return @QTD
END



IF OBJECT_ID ('[dbo].[Produto]','TR') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[Produto];  
GO  
CREATE TRIGGER reminder2  ON [dbo].[Produto] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE   
AS  

 DECLARE @IdProduto int, @Quantidade int;

 set @IdProduto = (SELECT IdProduto FROM INSERTED)
 set @Quantidade = (SELECT Quantidade FROM INSERTED)

 if(@Quantidade > dbo.getQuantidade(@IdProduto))
    begin
        RAISERROR ('Quantidade Pedida abaixo da quantidade do Stock', 16, 1); 
    end 
    else
    begin
        UPDATE Produto 
        SET ValorTotal = @Quantidade * getValor(@IdProduto);
        WHERE IdProduto = @IdProduto
    end
GO
```